# Maven Checkstyle plugin on Travis CI ignores source directories

Tags: java, maven, travis-ci, checkstyle

I have a project on GitHub, that builds on Travis CI. It was running
more or less fine until today. I updated configuration and now it uses
different paths. I integrated Delombok with my build and right now:

- Delombok processes `src/main/java` into `target/generated-sources/delombok`;
- `target/generated-sources/delombok` is set as project source directory, so most of the other plugins operate on it;
- but I want **Checkstyle** to only check my source code, not the generated one so I configured it to still process just `src/main/java`.

It works locally, works on my Jenkins, but fails on Travis.

This is the link to build that failed with debug flag turned on:
https://travis-ci.org/chilloutdevelopment/pl.chilldev.commons/builds/123777140

Here is the part of the configuration loading:

```
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (default)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
### skipped ###
  <propertyExpansion>checkstyle.project.basedir=/home/travis/build/chilloutdevelopment/pl.chilldev.commons</propertyExpansion>
### skipped ###
  <sourceDirectories default-value="${project.compileSourceRoots}">
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
  </sourceDirectories>
```

And this is the log from plugin execution:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check from
plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17,
parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo
'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check' with
basic configurator -->
### skipped ###
[DEBUG]   (f) propertyExpansion =
checkstyle.project.basedir=/home/travis/build/chilloutdevelopment/pl.chilldev.commons
### skipped ###
[DEBUG]   (f) sourceDirectories =
[/home/travis/build/chilloutdevelopment/pl.chilldev.commons/target/generated-sources/delombok]
```

`propertyExpansion` and `sourceDirectories` - these are the two
options set by my configuration - while `propertyExpansion` stays
correct, `sourceDirectories` turns back to default value.

Locally `sourceDirectories` is kept properly during plugin execution.

I have no clue what could that be - is that Travis problem, or on Maven/Checkstyle side?